# Ternary conditional - trying to add a class error

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Trying to apply the error class if the number returns - in it, but this isn't working - am I missing a character?

```
<td {`${this.state.number.toLocaleString()}`.includes("-") ? className=`${styles.red}` : ''}>
```

Answer (score 3):

A few issues with your approach.

First, do not try to toggle the inclusion of the `className` prop as a whole, simply give it an empty string value (or null) if you don't want a class.

Secondly, you don't need to wrap the state value in a template literal to run `includes()` - just do it directly

Do this instead:

```
<td className={this.state.number.toLocaleString().includes('-') ? styles.red : ''}>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
  <td {`${this.state.number.toLocaleString()}`.includes("-") ? className=`${styles.red}` : ''}>
```

To

```
   <td className={this.state.number.toLocaleString().includess("-") ? styles.red : ''}>
```